# Printing strings from all array elements

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I’ve tried to print all elements in an array as strings.

Following code goes segmentation fault .

Because some pointer of char don’t point at proper address.

```
char *print_array(char **s) {
        int i;
        char *ret;
        char *elm;
        char *myStr;
        strcat(myStr,"[");
        for (i = 0; s && s[i]; ++i){
                sprintf(elm,"\"%s\" ",s[i]);
                strcat(myStr,elm);
        }
        strcat(myStr,"]");
        ret = myStr;
        return ret;
} 
int main(){
        char *myArray[10] = {"4", "2", "11", "4", "15", "7", "9", "12", "3", "6"};;
        printf("## %s",print_array(myArray));
}
```

Then, how can I print strings from all elements in the array?

I mean above example uses 10 elements of array but I want print any array which never known how many elements and length of each element.

Does anyone knows good way?

Comment: You don't allocate any memory for the string where the numbers will go. So you don't know where it's pointing, and you're writing characters somewhere in memory. You have to `malloc` some space first.

Comment: How many size do I have to malloc when I don't know size of array?

Comment: Look at Joachim's answer. You have to pass the size, one way or another. And it's up to you to allocate a sufficient amount of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *print_array(char **s) {
    int i, n;
    size_t size =0;
    char *ret;

    for(i=0; s && s[i]; ++i)
        size += strlen(s[i]);

    n = i;//number of strings,
    if(ret = malloc(size + 2 + (n-1)*(n>0) + n*2 + 1)){//sumoflen(s) + [] + ' ' + "" + '\0'
        int len;
        char *p = ret;

        *p++ = '[';
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            len = sprintf(p, "\"%s\"", s[i]);
            p += len;
            if(i < n-1)
                *p++ = ' ';
        }
        *p++ = ']';
        *p = '\0';
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    char *myArray[] = {"4", "2", "11", "4", "15", "7", "9", "12", "3", "6", NULL};//last : Sentinel
    char *p;
    printf("## %s", p=print_array(myArray));
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `*(n>0)` mean? I have no idea of this syntax.

Comment: @user1345414 True is 1 (false is 0) logical expression in C.
 I put the condition number of spaces sandwiched between is n-1 but things get weird n is by -1 when 0.

Answer (score 2):

The short and only answer is: You need to tell the printing function how many items there is in the array.

*How* you do it doesn't matter, either as an argument, or you put in an extra item in the array as terminator, e.g. a `NULL` pointer (much like the strings themselves are terminated by a `'\0'` character). At the moment your printing function will most likely step outside the bounds of the array you pass in.

---

There's also other problems with your code, like you not allocating memory for neither `elm` nor `myStr`. And the `ret` variable is pretty useless.

Comment: I can print if I do `malloc`. Is it impossible to print dynamicaly created array?

Comment: @user1345414 Either allocate dynamically with [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc)/[`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), or by using fixed-sized arrays. If you use fixed-size arrays I recommend you use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) instead though.